# Running a compute function in ignite's embedded mode i.e. return transformed resultset

Tags: ignite

I am new to Ignite and would like to use Ignite in it's embedded mode. Is it possible to do computations on the ignite node like some sort of compute function that you can use in distributed mode?

Best,
ES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the best way to start with computations is to take a dive into Ignite docs here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.4/docs/compute-grid

You can also play with examples on how to use compute features listed in documentation:

https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/computegrid

However, it's a good practice to use embedded mode only for client nodes and keep server nodes as a set of standalone deployments.

Comment: To clarify, I want to use ignite just for it's in memory database features. Hence ignite will be embedded for me in the server node. There will only be once instance of my server meaning only one instance of ignite node. With this in mind, should I still be using compute grid?